# Is it possible to deep-link users to app/play store to download app and direct user to unique page?

Tags: android, ios

I want to be able to direct a specific user to the app/play store to download the app and when they open the app, deep-link them to a unique page. Is this possible or do I need to handle these links separately?

Comment: You like to add deep-link inside your app or outside app? if so where?

Comment: I'd like link to a create account page in the app

Answer (score 0):

You can handle deeplink as follows

```
String url = appContext.getString(R.string.app_scheme) + "://" + appContext.getString(R.string.host_home);
AppUtils.handleWebDeepLink(WebActivity.this, url);

public void handleWebDeepLink(Context context,String url){
    Uri uri=Uri.parse(url);
    Intent i=new Intent( Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
    try {
        context.startActivity( i );
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
        Logger.crashlyticsLogException( "While opening web deep link old:"+url , e );
    }
}
```